# Azure Search Nested Class Indexing

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I try to use Azure Search service for my application. I have a nested class like

```
public class Products
{
    String ProductName {get;set;}
    List<Order> Order  {get;set;}
}
public class Order
{
    String Name {get;set;}
}
```

and i couldn't find a way indexing products not only searching productname property but also searching ordername.

What is the way to handle this problem in Azure Search?

Comment: look at following doc- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/search-get-started-dotnet/

Comment: I have already looked at this link. There is no such a clue that answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Collection(Edm.String) field type? Take a look if the following index definition would work for you:

```
{
    "name": "products",  
    "fields": [
      {"name": "productId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false},
      {"name": "productName", "type": "Edm.String"},
      {"name": "orderNames", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"}
    ]
}
```

You could then index your documents like this:

```
{
   "value":[
      {
         "productId":"1",
         "productName":"product1",
         "orderNames":[
            "order1",
            "order2"
         ]
      },
      {
         "productId":"2",
         "productName":"product2",
         "orderNames":[
            "order1",
            "order2"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Alternatively you can you reverse Product - Order relationship and have Order as the main entity with all its properties including ProductName:

```
{
   "name":"orders",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"ordertId",
         "type":"Edm.String",
         "key":true,
         "searchable":false
      },
      {
         "name":"productName",
         "type":"Edm.String"
      },
      {
         "name":"orderName",
         "type":"Edm.String"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my order class includes geolocation properties that i also want to make some searches. That's why, this approach does not cover my needs. After making some researches there is a flattening data workaround but this workaround is only for DocumentDB i assume.

Comment: Can you reverse Product - Order relationship and have Order as the main entity with all its properties including ProductName?  {
    "name": "orders",  
    "fields": [
      {"name": "ordertId", "type": "Edm.String", "key": true, "searchable": false},
      {"name": "productName", "type": "Edm.String"},
      {"name": "orderName", "type": "Edm.String"}
    ]
}